# Carriage Return and Line Feed bit streams in a binary file during TFTP upload in ASCII mode

Tags: ftp, text, newlines, tftp

In case of TFTP, one can choose between "ASCII" or "octet" mode. As I have understood, 00001010(new-line) or 00001101(carriage return) bit streams in a binary file will get some sort of special treatment in ASCII mode? However, I created a file containing those characters:

```
root@A58:~# printf '\n' | xxd | xxd -r > bfile; printf '\r' | xxd | xxd -r >> bfile; printf 'A' | xxd | xxd -r >> bfile
root@A58:~# xxd -b bfile
0000000: 00001010 00001101 01000001                             ..A
root@A58:~#
```

..and when I uploaded this file from TFTP client to TFTP server using both "octet" and "netascii" modes, the file reached the TFTP server in same condition and had exactly the same content:

```
T42 ~ # cmp /srv/tftp/reverse_ascii /srv/tftp/reverse_binary 
T42 ~ #
```

Did I do something wrong? Or how should ASCII mode mangle the binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFTP uses similar mechanisms as telnet for transmitting ASCII. It follows the rules set out in the [NVT specification](http://www.hw-group.com/support/nvt/index_en.html#telnet). So effectively end-of-line markers are terminated with `<cr><lf>`, and if you want to send an actual `<cr>` then this is translated to `<cr><nul>`.

hexdumping a file I created:

```
00000000  0d 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67  33 0d 0a                 |.Testing3..|
```

However on transmission over tftp (got from a `tcpdump -X`):

```
0x0020:  0d00 5465 7374 696e 6733 0d00 0d0a       ..Testing3....
```

Note how the `<cr><lf>` sequence has been converted to `<cr><nul><cr><lf>`.

When I diff the results of the local and remote file, I end up with the same file. This will be because the `<cr><nul>` sequence will be returned back to `<cr>` and the local format (under unix) for a newline is `<lf>` and so the `<cr><lf>` is turned into `<lf>` and the original file as transmitted is received. I'm not so sure on how a DOS tftp server would handle the `<cr><nul><cr><lf>` sequence, I have a feeling it may mangle the output to have an extra `<cr>` (`<cr><nul>` becomes `<cr>` and `<cr><lf>` becomes `<cr><lf>`), especially given the RFC states:

```
A host which receives netascii mode data must translate the data to its own format.
```

**References**

[TFTP RFC, RFC1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) and the [Telnet NVT Specification](http://www.hw-group.com/support/nvt/index_en.html#telnet).